# Can there exists three sets: $A \subset B$, $B \in C$, $A \in C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can there exists three sets: $A \subset B$, $B \in C$, $A \in C$, if not, why not?, if yes, give an example.

My example:

A={$a,b$}

B={$a,b,c$}

C={{$a,b$},{$a,b,c$}}

Is this all? It seems this is a tricky question and there's something I'm missing. Thank you for your help!

Edit: fix typo

Comment: Except for one "}" you forgot, yes. If xour $\subset$ stands for $\subseteq$ and not $\subsetneq$, you could even use $A=B=\emptyset$, $C=\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Thank you!! I fixed the typo

Comment: [Kuratowski's version of ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition) is $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and this gives another example of what you want with $A=\{a\}$, $B=\{a,b\}$ and $C=(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written down in plain text, your question reduces to the existence of two sets, one of which a proper subset of the other such that they are both elements of a third set! There are infinitely many instances of triplets of sets satisfying such a configuration: for any set $A$ there must exist an object $a$ **not an element of it** (otherwise $A$ would become a universal set with respect to the relation of set-theoretical membership, situation which is prohibited by the axioms of almost any modern axiomatic system for formal mathematics); therefore, by setting $B=A \cup \{a\}$ you automatically have $A \subset B$; furthermore, by considering $C=\{A, B\}$ you will have obtained a triplet of sets as specified starting from any given set.

Answer (score 1):

If A if a subset of B and 
If B is an element or subset of C

Then A can only be a subset/element of C.

Thanks for clarifying. i misinterpreted the relationship b/w B and C.

Comment: B is an element of C, not a subset of C ( $B \in C$)

Answer (score 0):

My example given above is correct, therefore

$$\exists A,B,C \hookrightarrow A \subset B, A \in C, B \in C $$